# Angular 1.6.4 Inject service from external module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm creating a service on a separate module called 'hsHttp' -> HttpSrv. And I'm trying to use it from another module 'HttpApp'. I'm getting injector error: Error: [$injector:unpr]

My code is below:

"file1.js" => The service implementation

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("hsHttp", []);
    app.service("HttpSrv", function ($scope, $http) {
    ....
    });    
})();
```

"file2.js" => The service use implementation

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("HttpApp", ["hsHttp"]);
app.controller("HttpCtrl", HttpCtrl);
    function HttpCtrl($scope,HttpSrv) {
    ...
    }
})();
```

Why Angular can't inject the service from the other module ?

Thanks.
/yore

Comment: how are you loading the script files?

Comment: I create the module first. Then I run those. But the main problem was the $scope injected in the service. It was failing due to that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: service does not accept $scope as dependency. The solution is to remove the $scope from the definition:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("hsHttp", []);
    app.service("HttpSrv", function ($http) {
    ....
    });    
})();
```